# C# >NET 7 Trying to resolve services (with a Singleton) prior to Service Provider being built

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, oauth, .net-7.0

I'm using .NET 7 in a WebApplication with OAuth extensions.

The (GitHub) AuthenticationBuilder is added in the section of code before the application is built and the DI service provider is created.

However I need to work with a DI chain for UnitofWork/Repo/etc. Prior to the container being built.  Based on some reading I decided to instantiate a premature copy of the container in my anonymous method for the oAuth event.

Once I did that the UI prompted me with a warning that a second container was being built and I get that totally kills the concept of a Singleton and probably isn't a really good idea.

Are there any suggestions on how to handle working with the DB from within the oAuth.OnCreatingTicket event?  Or do I just need to pass configuration and manually instantiate all of the classes myself?

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork,UnitOfWork>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDocumentStore>(s => 
    DocumentStoreFactory.CreateStore(
        builder.Configuration["Server"], 
        builder.Configuration["Database"]));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(...)
    .AddCookie(...)
    .AddGitHub(o =>
    {
        o.ClientId = builder.Configuration["GitHub:ClientID"]!;
        o.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["GitHub:ClientSecret"]!;
        o.Events = new OAuthEvents
        {
            OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
            {
                //Building a temporary service provider so UnitOfWork/Service/DocumentStore DI chain can be fullfilled
                var sp = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
                await OauthPersistUser.HandleGitHubOauthTicket(context, sp.GetService(typeof(ILogger<>)), sp.GetService<IUnitOfWork>());
            }
        };
    });

var app = builder.Build();
//app Service provider Container is built and ready
```

Answer (score 0):

Several hours of playing around later I realized that the context passed by the oAuth provider has access to the service provider via ***HttpContext.RequestServices***.

so I can reduce my parameters to just the content, then grab the UnitOfWork object by:

```
public static async Task HandleGitHubOauthTicket(OAuthCreatingTicketContext context)
{
    var uow = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IUnitOfWork>();
    var log = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ILogger<OauthPersistUser>>();

        ...
}
```

Comment: While this might solve your original issue, note that this approach is known as a Service Locator pattern and in context of DI it's often viewed as [an anti-pattern](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/why-service-locator-is-an-anti-pattern-for-dependency-injection/), since it turns possible compile-time dependencies into runtime, thus having a higher potential to create bugs.